# Using PersistentStorage to my workdir deletes everything?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I'm using a PersistentVolume and a Claim and then mounting it to my workdir '/server' to create a simple Minecraft server using K8s, and when I deploy it the jar file isn't there anymore?[image]

```
deployment.yaml
---------------
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: minecraft-pvstorage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: minecraft-pvclaim
      containers:
        - name: minecraft-deployment
          image: localhost:32000/minecraft:1.18.2-new
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 30007
          volumeMounts:
            - name: minecraft-pvstorage
              mountPath: /server
```

```
pv.yaml
-------
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: minecraft-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/minecraft"
```

```
pvclaim.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: minecraft-pvclaim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Can anyone help me with this? It works when I delete the volumeMounts from the deployment.yaml.

Comment: Providing your pvc and pv yaml file would help people to answer your question.

Comment: Just added it now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

In my deployment.yaml I defined a mount for just the world and that ended up saving all of the world data.

```
deployment.yaml
--------------
volumeMounts:
    - name: minecraft-pvstorage
      mountPath: /server/1.18.2/world
      subPath: world
```

Answer (score 1):

When you mount something onto a directory in the image that already has content, the content in the image becomes *obscured*, i.e. hidden and replaced with the content of the mount.

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container

Comment: Ah I see, do you have any idea how I could do this somewhere in my yaml file?

Comment: Can you mount your persistent volume on another path than /server?

Comment: Yeah, if I do that the server runs fine as /server is not being obscured

Comment: I don't know anything about Minecraft servers, so I don't know how to have the world map in the mount and everything else in the image - which is what I'd think you want to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.